# What is the odd paper inside a computer LCD?

Tags: lcd

So some friends and I were smashing an old, broken laptop; and we found this odd film like paper inside the LCD screen. When you look through it, it seems to act like a prism, as everything becomes colorful. Also, if you look through it at an angle, the paper seems like it is reflecting the light in front of you up into your eyes. Also, one side you can look through, the other side is mostly reflective.

I know this question is quite vague, but I am completely puzzled as to what this stuff is called or how to describe it.

Comment: Oh great, now everybody will smash their old monitors and notebooks to have a look...  ;-)..I wonder if you could make polarized sunglasses out of that stuff.

Comment: Reminds me of the first time I took a lawnmower engine apart in 1973, did not have a socket set, so I used a hammer to have a peek at the magical innards,and yes it was magic to me at the time....

Comment: @Moab Thats what we did :P We named them LSD Specs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably looking at the [polarizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_crystal_display#Overview).

[image]

Comment: What explains better how something works than pictures and a video? http://www.instructables.com/id/Privacy-monitor-made-from-an-old-LCD-Monitor/

Comment: I prefer Dinner and a Movie.  ;-)

Comment: That looks like it! Now to try out that instructable link and see if it is the same on other monitors.